# How to get lowerCamelCase in Request body?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, jackson-databind

I have created a class as follows:

```
class Student{
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    int rollNumber;

}
```

and also I have a controller as follows:

```
public void processStudentDetails(@RequestBody final Student student){}
```

Using `@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.LowerCaseStrategy.class)`, I can take parameters in the body in lower case.

But how can I take parameters in the request body in lowerCamelCase form?

Answer (score 0):

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.LowerCamelCaseStrategy.class)
```

Comment: There is no such nested class LowerCamelCaseStrategy in PropetyNamingStrategies

Comment: It was added in Jackson 2.12